# Why can I not import this country code picker? Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to implement a drop down bar that allows users to select their country along with the phone code. I am following this article but it is giving me errors when trying to import it.

https://reactnativeexample.com/a-searchable-dropdown-component-to-select-a-country-code-with-react-native/

```
import { CallingCodePicker } from 'rn-country-code-picker';
```

error ->
Unable to resolve module 'rn-country-code-picker' from 'src\pages\PhoneVerification.js': rn-country-code-picker could not be found within the project.

I installed it with no issues, is there a better way to do this type of thing? Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@digieggs/rn-country-code-picker is the node module you're talking about, you're missing `@digieggs` at the begining of the import.

```js
import { CallingCodePicker } from '@digieggs/rn-country-code-picker';
```

This is a scoped package and requires the namespace upon importing. Just to make sure, you also need this namespace when installing:

```
yarn add @digieggs/rn-country-code-picker
```

or

```
npm install @digieggs/rn-country-code-picker
```

Comment: ok so that fixed that error, now I am getting a blank screen though and my app is not loading, do you need to see more code? It mentioned something about

Failed to compile.
C:/Users/Justin/Desktop/Clubbit/FirstTry/node_modules/@codler/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/lib/KeyboardAwareHOC.js 13:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| } from 'react-native'

Comment: I am not sure if that has anything to do with it though

Comment: I'm not really a react native expert but that seems like a different issue. Sounds like your workflow is trying to compile a certain type of file, but you haven't added the correct loaders to compile that file type. For example in webpack if you want to compile Sass files you need the sass-loader package and you need to add it as a loader. In your case idk what loader you might be missing, but it sounds like a similar type of issue based on that error you commented.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [react-native-country-picker-modal](https://github.com/GetWala/react-native-country-picker-modal)

```
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  StatusBarIOS,
  PixelRatio
} from 'react-native';

import CountryPicker from 'react-native-country-picker-modal';

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    StatusBarIOS.setHidden(true);
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cca2: 'US'
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to Country Picker !
        </Text>
        <CountryPicker
          onSelect={(value)=> this.setState({country: value, cca2: value.cca2})}
          cca2={this.state.cca2}
          translation='eng'
        />
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          press on the flag
        </Text>
        {this.state.country &&
          <Text style={styles.data}>
            {JSON.stringify(this.state.country, null, 2)}
          </Text>
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    fontSize: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#888',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  data: {
    padding: 15,
    marginTop: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    borderColor: '#888',
    borderWidth: 1 / PixelRatio.get(),
    color: '#777'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('example', () => Example);
```